# Select & automate rename columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, rename

I searched before asking this but either I didn't understand the reply or the answer wasn't adapted to my case.

This is my [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3yg.png)

With this code :
`gini.iloc[:, 2:].rename(columns=lambda x : x[:4])`

I have the result that I want, [preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLJNP.png). To know, rename 2000 [YR2000] to 2000, same for the other columns.

But I want to assign this modification in my original df. When I add `inplace = True` in the rename function, I get a copy warning that I don't know how to resolve.

Secondly, I don't know how to assign this change to my original df, keeping my first two columns intact.

Thanks ! I hope I'm clear, it's my first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a fairly easy way:

```
cols = df.columns
renames = {col: col[:4] for col in cols[2:]}
df.rename(columns=renames, inplace=True)
```